# Are my applications safe from the GDPR suspension?

Tags: android, privacy, policy

I have some basic android apps with AdMob serving ads and almost year ago one of my applications on Android Play Store have been temporarily suspended after new GDPR rules with the explanation of how I need to update Privacy Policy link in Store Listing. After updating Privacy Policy link, my app got unsuspended.

After that (June 2018.) I have updated all of my apps which are using AdMob with Privacy Policy link (GDPR compliant) stored on Google sites, and also prompting users on first start with checkbox (I have read Privacy Policy) and Accept button. Also, user can read Privacy Policy in settings again.

Since then (10 months), my apps are running fine without any warnings. Should I be concerned or is it fine to leave apps like that? I don't use consent SDK or anything else. I have few apps where I plan to add AdMob ads, and I am wondering is it safe to do it like with previous apps.

One of my apps: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lampa.SaVaVoiceRecorder

And here I plan to put ads: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sladjan.music

Thank You!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about complying with laws, not computer programming. Stack Overflow is not a law office. Please talk to a qualified legal advisor.

Comment: I just wanted to know other developers experiences with this problem. Thanks for the nice welcome.

Comment: "I just wanted to know other developers experiences with this problem" -- that is not the role of Stack Overflow. You might consider some Android development discussion boards, such as those on Reddit.

Answer (score -1):

StackOverflow has a wide stack exchange community maybe there you will find a better answer. In my experience developers here on stack overflow tend to reply only on coding problem. That's all I can say.